# How do you pull data from a .FIC file in java?

Tags: java

So I am writing a scrabble word suggestion program that I decided to do because I wanted to learn sets (don't worry, I at least got that part) and referencing info/data not created within the program. Im pretty new to Java (and programming in general), but I was wondering how to pull words from a word list .FIC file in order to check them against words generated from the letters inputted.

To clarify, I have written a program which takes a series of letters and returns a set of every possible word created from those letters. for example:
input:

```
abc
```

would give a set containing the "words":

```
a, ab, ac, abc, acb, b, ba, bc, bac, bca, c, ca, cb, cab, cba
```

What I am asking, really, is how to check those to find the ones contained in the .FIC file.

The file is the "official crosswords" file from the [Moby project word list](http://icon.shef.ac.uk/Moby/mwords.html) and I am still (very) shaky on parsing and other file dealing-with methods. I am continuing to research so I dont have any prototype code for that.

Sorry if the question isn't entirely clear.

edit: here is the method that makes the "words" to make it easier to understand the idea. The part I don't understand is specifically how to pull a word(as a string) from the .FIC file.

```
private static Set<String> Words(String s)
{
    Set<String> tempwords = new TreeSet<String>();
    if (s.length() == 1)
    {   // base case, last letter
        tempwords.add(s);
    //  System.out.println(s);                                            uncomment when debugging
    }
    else
    {
        //set up to add each letter in s
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {   //cut the i letter out of the string
            String remaining = s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i+1);
            //recursion to add all combinations of letters onto the current letter/"word"
            for (String permutation : Words(remaining))
            {
            //  System.out.println(s.substring(i, i+1) + permutation);    uncomment when debugging

                //add the full length words
                tempwords.add(s.substring(i, i+1) + permutation);
            //  System.out.println(permutation);                          uncomment when debugging

                //add the not-full-length words
                tempwords.add(permutation);
            }
        }
    }
//  System.out.println(tempwords);                                        uncomment when debugging
    return tempwords;
}
```

Comment: What's a .FIC file?  (Show us an example file, your parsing and search/matching code, what you expect that code to do and what it actually does.)

Comment: It's just a list of words, one per line. Just needs to read the file by lines and add the words to a hashmap or trie for matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if it is the best solution, but i figured it out (hobbs the line thing helped a lot, thank you). I found that this works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:/Users/Sean/workspace/Imbored/bin/113809of.fic"));
    while(true)
    {
        words.clear();
        String letters = enterLetters();
        words.addAll(Words(letters));
        while(s.hasNextLine()) {
             String line = s.nextLine();
             String finalword = checkWords(line, words);
             if (finalword != null) finalwordset.add(finalword);
        }
        s.reset();
        System.out.println(finalwordset);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("_________________________________________________________________________");
    }
}
```

A few things:

1. The checkWords method checks if the current word from the file is in the generated list of "words"
2. The enterletters method takes user inputted letters and returns them in a string
3. The Words method returns a set of strings of all of the possible combinations of the characters in the given string, with each character used up to as many times as it appears in the string and no repeated "words" in the returned set.
4. finalwordset and words are arraylists of strings defined as instance variables(i would put them in the main method but I'm lazy and it doesn't matter for this case)
5. I am very sure there is a better/more efficient way to do this, but this at least works.
6. Finally: I decided to answer rather than delete because I didn't see this answered anywhere else, so if it is feel free to delete the question or link to the other answer or whatever, at this point it is to help other people.